# Why does my Matlab function script not pick up variables I have described in the main script?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Could someone please assist in helping me fix my code?
Also, why do I get an error in my function script when I call a variable I have defined in my main script?
I have defined kprime yet when I run the function script I get no response.

Main Script:

```
%% Define constants
p.k=0.02; %lb.mol/atm.lbmcat.h @ 260°C
p.T=260; % Isothermal termperature in °C
p.P0=10; % Initial feed pressure (atm)
p.void=0.45; % bed void fraction
p.rho=120; % catalyst particle density(lbm/ft^3)
p.ttubes=1000; % Total tubes ( 10x100)
p.Dcatalyst=0.25/12; % diameter of catalyst particles(ft)
p.Dtubes=1.5/12; % diameter of tubes
p.ya0=0.24; % mole fraction Ethylene

%% Define parameters
Pa0=p.P0*p.ya0; % Partial pressure (atm)
Ac=pi*((p.Dcatalyst^2)/2); % cross-sectional area of particle
epsilon=p.ya0*-0.5; % Epsilon from stochiometry where delta = (1-0.5-1)=-0.5
kprime=p.k*Pa0*0.5^(2/3); %lb.mol/h.lbmcat

%% Define Weight region of interest
N=p.ttubes*Ac *(p.rho*(1-p.void)); % Final weight (lbm)
W= linspace (0,N,100); % Weight of catalyst across tube length (lbm)

%% Parameter inital conditions evaluation per tube
Fa0=(2.4*(10^-4))*3600; % Initial flowrate of A (lb mol/h) 
Fb0=((1.2*(10^-4))*3600);% Initial flowrate of B (lb mol/h)
Fi0=((1.2*(10^-4))*3600)*(0.79/0.21);% Initial flowrate of Inerts (N2) (lb mol/h)
F0= [Fa0;Fb0;Fi0]; % Vector of initial conditions
mA0=Fa0*28; % mass flowrate of A (lb/h)
mB0=Fb0*32; %mass flowrate of B (lb/h)
mI0=Fi0*28; %mass flowrate of I (lb/h)
mT=mA0+mB0+mI0; % total mass flowrate(lb/h)
G=mT/Ac; % Superficial mass velocity (lb/hft^2)
v=0.0673;   % superficial velocity (lbm/ft.h) (Tabulated data for air @260°C, 10atm)
rho0=0.413; %gas density (lb/ft^3) (Tabulated data for air @260°C, 10atm)
Beta=((G*(1-p.void))/((4.17*10^8)*rho0*p.Dcatalyst*(p.void^3))*((150*(1-p.void)*v )/p.Dcatalyst)+1.75*G ); % Beta value (atm/ft) Check eq
alpha=(2*Beta)/(Ac*(1-p.void)*p.rho*p.P0);% alpha value (/lbcat)

%% Define weight varying variables 
u.X=@(W) Conversion(W) % Conversion change with weight 
u.y=@(W) Pressure(W); % Pressure drop with variable weight
f=(1+epsilon*u.X(W))/y; % Ratio of volumetric flowrate down reactor
raprime=kprime*(1-u.X(W))/(1+epsilon*u.X(W)) *y; % Reaction rate with variable weight

function dXdW = Conversion(W, X)

dXdW= (kprime/Fa0)*((1-X)/(1+epsilon*X))*y ;

function dydW= Pressure(W,y)
dydW  =-(alpha)*(1+epsilon*X)/(2*y);
```

Comment: "the function script" -- It's either a function or a script, not both. Functions have their own workspace, they don't see stuff defined in other workspaces. You have pass the values into the function as parameters. Or you have to explicitly use `global` variables, but this is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

In general, functions have their own separate workspaces. So your Conversion( ) function only sees what is passed into it, namely W and X. Likewise your Pressure( ) function only sees W and y. You will either need to pass in those other variables into your functions, or make them visible to your functions by using nested functions. E.g., you could turn your outer script into a function to make the other functions nested:

```
function my_function % add this line

%% Define constants
p.k=0.02; %lb.mol/atm.lbmcat.h @ 260°C
    :
function dXdW = Conversion(W, X)
dXdW= (kprime/Fa0)*((1-X)/(1+epsilon*X))*y ;
end
function dydW= Pressure(W,y)
dydW  =-(alpha)*(1+epsilon*X)/(2*y);
end

end % add this line
```

Now those last two functions will see all the variables in the calling function.
The other errors you are getting is because you don't call your last two functions with the proper number of input arguments.

Comment: Thank you James. Appreciate it and will edit my functions and hopefully get what I need

Comment: Note that this answer adds `end` 3 times. When using nested functions, all functions in the file must have an `end` statement. Without these statements, the functions are assumed to be local functions, not nested functions.

Comment: @Cris: Good catch ... I forgot I added those also.